# Barra de progresso com Dialog (Shell Script)

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, dialog

Eu gostaria de criar uma barra de progresso para o meu script de backup. O problema é que o comando do rsync (que fica dentro do loop) gera linhas duplicadas (desnecessárias) que aumentam o tamanho do arquivo de log. Eu já incluí dentro do loop o comando `uniq -u` para gerar linhas únicas, mas esse comando causa um bug na barra de progresso do dialog (trava a barra). Veja um trecho do meu código abaixo.

```
dialog --infobox 'Iniciando Backup...' 3 25; sleep 1
  declare -i cont=1
  {
  while [ $cont -le 100 ]; do
    echo $cont
    cont=$((cont+1))
    rsync -avh --progress "/home/$USER/Documentos" "/home/$USER/Backup/" --log-file=arquivo.log
    uniq -u arquivo.log
  done
  } | dialog --gauge 'Aguarde... Copiando Arquivos' 8 70 0
  dialog --msgbox 'Backup concluído com sucesso!' 6 35
  dialog --title 'Log de Backup' --textbox "$ARQUIVO_LOG" 0 0
```

Não sei como consertar isso, alguém saberia como aperfeiçoar esse código? Por favor testem esse código e proponham melhorias. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode redirecionar `stderr` a `stdout` com `2>&1` assim:

```
ARQUIVO_LOG=arquivo.log
dialog --infobox 'Iniciando Backup...' 3 25; sleep 1
  declare -i cont=1
  {
  while [ $cont -le 100 ]; do
    echo $cont
    cont=$((cont+1))
    rsync -avh --progress "/home/$USER/Downloads" "/home/$USER/Downloads.bak/" --log-file=$ARQUIVO_LOG 2>&1
    uniq -u $ARQUIVO_LOG
  done
  } | dialog --gauge 'Aguarde... Copiando Arquivos' 8 70 0
  dialog --msgbox 'Backup concluído com sucesso!' 6 35
  dialog --title 'Log de Backup' --textbox "$ARQUIVO_LOG" 0 0
```

Fica ótimo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]